# How to convert ShortCode to Gutenberg Block?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have shortcode in functions.php:

```
function video( $atts, $content = null ) {
        return '<div class="videoWrapper"><iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' .$content. '" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'video', 'video' );
```

I used it as:

```
[video]videoID[/video]
```

Output is:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

I have weird keyboard and I don't know how to type `[]`, so whenever I need it, I need to google it or open existing post to copy it and post shortcode, so it would be much easier if I can predefine Gutenberg block that will on click add `[video]videoID[/video]` or `[video="videoID"]`

Comment: I think there is already a Gutenberg block for YouTube videos. You just have to paste the video link into it. Plus another one for HTML, if you must have the video in an iframe, where, again, you just have to paste your code. It's pointless to add a function for something that already exists.

Comment: I am asking this because I don't use only YouTube videos.

Comment: Are u finded answer?